# .js files replaced with garbage (html content ) of exactly the same size while installing with NSIS

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, antivirus

While the installation of our software, on at least one PC, some files are replaced by html content and python of exactly the same size of the previous file, the creation date is exactly the same as others files. I suppose the antivirus (AVG free ) might be at fault, it look like the antivirus allocate memory to analyse the file, fail to read it and then write what was in memory at that place instead of the file.

I don't own that PC, so I have limited diagnostic possibilities. Did someone experienced similar issues and found a workaround around it ? May be renaming the file to a different extension ? I'm listening to your suggestions...

Comment: Wow. This sounds like it is really crap to troubleshoot. Hope you post the solution, if you find it - just to satisfy my curiosity. ;-)